# I injected a dll into a process, so how to call the functions of target process?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I am wondering is that possible to call target process's functions from a injected dll. If yes, how to do that?

I am newbie so any advices/clues/references are welcome. Thank you~

Comment: maybe you could use CreateRemoteThread http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "Function")`
`GetModuleHandle(NULL)` returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it surely is... You need to create an API which allows the program to register some sort of callbacks which can be accessed by the logic in the DLL.